# Healthcheck for Cosmodb emulator in docker

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose

I've got a docker-compose file with following container defined:

```
cosmosdb:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.cosmosdb
    environment:
      - NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "8900:8900"
      - "8901:8901"
      - "8979:8979"
      - "10250:10250"
      - "10251:10251"
      - "10252:10252"
      - "10253:10253"
      - "10254:10254"
      - "10255:10255"
      - "10256:10256"
      - "10350:10350"
    networks:
      my-network:
        ipv4_address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And a Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install curl -y

CMD /usr/local/bin/cosmos/start.sh
```

My question is, what is a good way to add a healthcheck here?

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but just ran into the same issue.

I guess you can try invoking the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/), but the request isn't trivial to construct. See an example [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-db-rest-samples/blob/main/Program.cs).

Alternatively, the output looks something like this:

```
This is an evaluation version.  There are [123] days left in the evaluation period.
Starting
Started 1/2 partitions
Started 2/2 partitions
Started
```

You can redirect the output to a file and `grep` for `Started`.
(looks like this isn't logged to a file in addition to the console, and I haven't found any [flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator-command-line-parameters) to configure it).